# Crontab scheduled bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, output

I want to automate speedtest.net and test my network connection to specific server ID 36250 every 5 minutes.

Ive installed official speedtestCLI and wrote a script called *run_speedtest.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

date_now=`date "+%H:%M:%S       %d/%m/%y"`
result=/home/zaz/speedtesty/results
speedtest -s 36250 >> result
echo "$date_now" >> result
```

Now to automate things Ive edited my crontab file by using command: *sudo crontab -e* and it looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /home/zaz/speedtesty/run_speedtest.sh
```

*results* file is created, however only output in my *results* file are rows with current date. If I run script by typing bash run_speedtest.sh I get output in *results* that I want (speedtest measure + date)

Im a Ubuntu newbie, can someone help me out?

Comment: How did you install the speedtest CLI?

Answer (score 1):

If run via *cron*, the script runs with different permissions (with a different user account) than when you run it from the shell. So it might or might not find your *speedtest* command; specify the full path for it.

Also, since you create a variable *result* in the script, you probably want to use the variable, not a plain file *result* in the current directory (which is probably the root directory when run via *cron*, and writing there may fail because of permissions). Use `>>$result`, not `>> result`.

And finally, I'd simply use a loop and `sleep 600` (sleep for 600 seconds) instead of going through the hassle with a crontab which you might forget sooner or later, and then you keep speed-testing forever. ;-)

Comment: "the script runs with different permissions (with a different user account)" Depends on which crontab you added it to. OP could have added it to their `crontab`, in which case it would have run as their user..